# How to loop through a cell three times to do a multi find & replace?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to do a Find/Replace and I'm getting stuck.  Basically, I want to copy the contents of a cell, let's say it is cell P6.  I want to put the conents of that cell 8 cells to the left.

So, in CellAddress of P6 I have the following:
1. Campaign Name = YES 
2. Campaign / Program Manager = YES 
30. Creative Indicator = YES 
Q1. New  Legal Approval = YES 
Q2. Targeting Indicator = YES

In cell H6, I want to see this:
1. Campaign Name
2. Campaign / Program Manager
30. Creative Indicator
Q1. New  Legal Approval
Q2. Targeting Indicator

Basically, anything with "YES", "NO", or "=" is replaced with "".  I see what the problem with the loop is...I just can't seem to fix it.

Here is my non-working code.

```
fndList = Array("NO", "YES", "=")
rplcList = Array("", "", "")
    For x = LBound(fndList) To UBound(fndList)
        ActiveSheet.Range("AA1").Value = Replace(ActiveSheet.Range(CellAddress).Value, fndList(x), rplcList(x))
        ActiveSheet.Range(CellAddress).Offset(0, -8).Value = ActiveSheet.Range("AA1").Value
        ActiveSheet.Range("AA1").Clear
    Next
```

This is the problem.  On the first iteration through the loop I get this:
1. Campaign Name = YES 2. Campaign / Program Manager = YES 30. Creative Indicator = YES Q1. New Legal Approval = YES Q2. Targeting Indicator = YES

On the second iteration, I get this:
1. Campaign Name =  2. Campaign / Program Manager =  30. Creative Indicator =  Q1. New Legal Approval =  Q2. Targeting Indicator =

On the third iteration, I get this:
1. Campaign Name YES 2. Campaign / Program Manager YES 30. Creative Indicator YES Q1. New Legal Approval YES Q2. Targeting Indicator YES

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get that string once and work on it, i.e.:

```
Dim str as string: str = ActiveSheet.Range(CellAddress).Value
For x = LBound(fndList) To UBound(fndList)
    str = Replace(str, fndList(x), rplcList(x))
Next x

ActiveSheet.Range(CellAddress).Offset(0, -8).Value = str
```

However, be aware that this will not replace the patterns as "whole words", they will be replaced even inside other words if they appear.

Comment: I knew that was it!  It's too late in the day to do work now.  Heading home.
Thanks ASH!!!